# Electron & Node.js MySQL how to write a console.log before an Error?

Tags: mysql, node.js, electron

I use the MySQL node module and I have loop where I will get some stuff from my DB. When all files are flaged as used=1 I will run into this error because no more stuff to get :)

```
Cannot read property 'sample_column' of undefined
```

Everything is fine and this is how it should be but I need to write a console.log before the error but it´s not working any idea?

```
        var query = "Select * from sample.logs where used = '0' order by id asc LIMIT 1"

        connection.query(query, function (error, results, fields){
        if(error) {
        console.log('HELLO PLEASE SEE ME :)')
        }
        else{
        // ..   
        }
        })
```

Please notice that I use Electron and I see the console.log only in the Inspector like you have in every website. I only get red error code!

Comment: The error is occurring because of something you are doing inside `else { ...`.

Comment: Yes you are right! Thank you so much :)

Answer (score 0):

Answer was given by @Michael
After everything was flagged as used=1 we didn´t enter if error we enter instead the else area and if I would enter a console.log at the beginning of the else area I can see it again!